# Example on: $μ_n$ converges weakly to $μ$, but $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ for any $x$

Tags: probability

Please somebody who provide me an example that the the probability distributions $μ_n$ and $μ$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure,  $μ_n$ converges weakly to $μ$, but $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ for any $x$.

Comment: I presume that $f_n $ is the Lebesgue  density of $\mu_n $?

Comment: Yes, $f_n$  is the Lebesgue density of $μ_n$, and $f$ for $\mu$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

On $(0,\pi),$ let $f_n(x) = (2/\pi)\sin^2(nx).$ The corresponding probability measures converge weakly to the uniform measure on $(0,\pi),$ by the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

If $x\in (0,\pi)$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi,$ then as is well known, $e^{inx}$ is dense in the unit circle. If $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi,$ then $e^{inx}$ is cyclic but will take on enough different values so that $f_n(x)$ cannot converge. Thus for all $x\in (0,\pi),$ $f_n(x)$ fails to converge.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x) = 2$ if $x \in [0,1]$ with $\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor$ odd, $0$ otherwise.  Then the probability measures $\mu_n$ converge weakly to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, but $|f_n(x) - 1| = 1$ everywhere.